# Format time in google gauge chart

Tags: api, charts, google-visualization, gauge

Is there anyway to format Google Gauge chart from seconds to time like this?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using object notation, you can provide a value (`v:`) and a formatted value (`f:`)

`{v: 4.2, f: '01:16:04'}`

the gauge chart will display the formatted value

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Label', 'Value'],
      [' ', {v: 4.2, f: '01:16:04'}]
    ]);

    var options = {
      height: 240,
      max: 5,
      minorTicks: 5,
      redFrom: 3.25,
      redTo: 5,
      yellowFrom: 1.65,
      yellowTo: 3.25,
      width: 240
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages:['gauge']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```