# How to add text into Google Chart value text

Tags: google-visualization

I am currently working with Google chart, Gauge chart. i want to add **%** along with the data value. How can I do that.

Screen shot is attached for reference.

I want to make **3.9%** rather than only **3.9** at bottom

[image]

EDIT

```
this.data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Label', 'Value'],
    ['Download%', {v:0,f:'0%'}]
  ]);
```

And in my update function

```
    drawChart() {

        this.data.setValue(0, 1, this.progress);
        this.chart.draw(this.data, this.options);

  }
```

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40720965/5090771) -- basically use object notation for the data cell -- provide both a value (`v:`) and a formatted value (`f:`) -- instead of using the value `3.9` -- use --> `{v: 3.9, f: '3.9%'}`

Comment: Please see the EDIT, I am still not getting % after value.